# Simple Communication with a Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm looking for a very simple way to communicate with a thread in Java.  Consider the following example:

```
boolean pass=false;
Thread simpleThread=new Thread(){
  public void run(){
    x=doStuff();
    if (x==0) pass=true;
  }
}
simpleThread.start();
```

I just need to know if doStuff() returned a zero or not.  Of course, this is not legal in Java, but how do I implement it properly?  It appears that I need some sort of Object that can be written by simpleThread and read by the main thread.  What is that missing piece?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using an AtomicBoolean:

```
final AtomicBoolean pass = new AtomicBoolean(false); //making this final means we can access it in the anonymous Thread instance
Thread simpleThread=new Thread(){
  public void run(){
    x=doStuff();
    if (x==0) pass.set(true);
  }
}
simpleThread.start();
...
pass.get(); //of course, this could return false simply because the newly spawned thread has not completed execution yet
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  It's so simple.  AtomicBoolean blew me away!

Comment: I don't fully understand the use of `AtomicBoolean` in this example. This example does not rely on "compare and swap" semantics, which to my knowledge is the main motivation to use atomics. Using a traditional volatile boolean should be equivalent.

Comment: @bluenote10 the example is using `AtomicBoolean` more as a simple boolean holder. A volatile boolean is not possible here because all declarations are local scope and only a local final is accessible in an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Anyway I upvoted @JonSkeet for his answer and I rather enjoy the outcome of this question as it demonstrates that a low quality answer which addresses the OPs attempt directly can outrank a high quality answer which requires larger changes to do things right.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use [`Future<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Instead of starting a new thread directly like this, you'd probably use an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and pass it a [`Callable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). That would return a `Future<T>` for you.

You could then ask the `Future<T>` at any time (from the original thread) whether it has already finished, or just block until it *has* finished (optionally with a timeout).

You can do the equivalent manually with a shared variable, but personally I think the `Future`/`Callable` approach is cleaner in the case where you're effectively computing a single (possibly complex) value on a different thread. If you need to *regularly* communicate with the thread (e.g. to give it more work, or see progress) then it's not as appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a shared object that the two threads can see. The object must be modifiable. That is, you cannot use primitives or basic object types like String, Integer, Boolean, etc. as they are immutable.

You also need to understand and use thread synchronization.

Here is an example using a list:

```
List mylist = new ArrayList();

in-thread
{
   synchronized( mylist )
   {
       mylist.add( _something_ );
   }
}

in-another-thread
{
   synchronized( mylist )
   {
       mylist.get( 0 ); // do something with result;
   }
}
```

Comment: May also want to look into the atomic classes: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

Comment: without doubt the way to go for getting the result of a spawned computation is "Future" (see  @jon skeet)

Comment: true, re Future, but there is no magic in Future/Callable/ExecutorService. These are just utilities for doing the above basic communication between threads. It is helpful for every good Java developer to know Java threading primitives even when choosing to use utilities that hide these concepts somewhat.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the first thread will acquire the lock first. In which case myList will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  All I really need is a Boolean but it is immutable.  What's the best mutable alternative to Boolean?

Comment: Re Peter Lawrey, that's correct. This just handles data hand-off, not notification. For that, wait()/notify() mechanism could be used.

Comment: Re wanting mutable Boolean, there really isn't a ready-made solution. I frequently see a hack of using a list or a 1-length array. Another approach is to write your own class with a getter and setter for the boolean value. I have also seen and written generic mutable reference class that you parameterize with type that it should hold. Easy enough to write. Similar to how the whole Future utility works.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate @Jon's suggestion.

```
ExecutorService executor = ...

Future<Integer> result = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call() {
        return doStuff();
    }
});

// later.
Integer x = result.get();
boolean pass = x==0;
```